# LLBLGenPro + VB6 project - accessing new columns added to a typedlist

Tags: vb6, llblgenpro

I have a program made in Visual Basic 6 which access data from a database (made with Microsoft SQL server management studio express 2000 then migrated to 2005) and puts all data into an immense GridView.

The views, typedlists, queries, etc... all have to go through LLBLGenPro, which is used from what i learned to regenerate the entire code of our program in case we need to add anything. The project on LLBL contains entities, typedlists and typedviews. I'm not a pro of LLBLGenPro and i'm just starting to discover it

I have to add two columns to the Gridview with two specific tables columns containing the information i need. So i went onto the database to modify the view i needed to get the required data (which now gives me the two more desired rows), then i loaded the database again in LLBLGenPro and made sure to check my new fields in the typedList that contains them. I regenerated the program, and 
started the visual basic project. My columns appear in all the files where they should be, with the right names (the typedlist and the views referring to it). The classes now find 23 column indexes instead of 21. All seems fine for now.

The typedList is then imported into the main class:

```
Private _typedList As New DBSqlTypedList.MyClassNameTypedListTypedList
```

All the items from the table in the DB are already loaded correctly by the code using filters and appear in the program without problem. The typedlist we need (imported as `_typedList`) fills the data in the gridview (GridBT) with the following lines:

```
If isOpenSoftware Then
                With Me.gridBT
                    .AutoGenerateColumns = True
                    .AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle = Nothing
                    .DataSource = _typedList
```

Now here's the problem: `_typedList` does not see my two news rows at all and they don't appear in the grid at all.

Typing `_typedList.item(0).xxxx` for example gives me access to all the rows that were already there but none of the two i added appear in it.

Did I forget something in LLBLGenPro?

Don't hesitate to tell me if you think i didn't send enough code or information!